# Android 4.2 Presentation doesn't recognize external display

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, presentation

I've tryed to run `ApiDemos` from samples, it says that there is only one display. External display connected via HDMI and currently it works as a mirror display. I have Acer A511 with AOKP formware.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Talk to the maintainers of the "AOKP formware", pointing out your issue.

Comment: Can it be device design issue? I've changed firmware to CM 10.1 and got the same

Comment: @skayred: "Can it be device design issue?" -- possibly. You will have better luck asking the maintainers of the ROM mods in question.

Comment: Is there any easy way to fix it with CyanogenMod sources e.g.?

Comment: @skayred: **Please contact the maintainers of the ROM mods in question**. They have their own Web sites and ways of getting support.